# How can I display the td of a table without repeating it several times?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, ejs

I have a database that has a table. In this table there is the user's name, the user's number, the course, and the level he has taken. When the user takes two courses, the data is repeated twice (name, number) and then the course and its level. I would like to display this database in a table. I would like to have one username and number displaying his two courses in one row of the table.

It is my code:

```
<table id="bootstrap-data-table-export" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>M Code</th>
            <th>Numbering</th>
            <th>Cours Level</th>
            <th>Point</th>
            <th>Graduation</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <%
        var c =[]
        //console.log(membre);
        for (let i = 0; i < membre.length; i++) {
            var element = membre[i];
            //console.log("membre[i].username== ", membre[i].username);
            for (let j = 0; j < c.length; j++) {
                var element1 = c[j];
                if (membre[i].username == c[j]) {
                    console.log("username = ", i,' ', element.username);
                    console.log("c[j] = ", j,' ', c[j]);
                } else { %>
                <% }
            }
            c.push(element.username)
        %>
                
                    
                    
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <%= membre[i].username %>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <%= membre[i].mcode %>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <%= membre[i].num_agent %>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <select class="form-control selectPoints">
                        <option class="text-center" value="1"><%= membre[i].cours %> - niveau</option>
                        <option class="text-center" value="1">egal egal</option>
                    </select>
                    
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <select class="form-control selectPoints">
                            <option class="text-center" value="1">Cours Name 5pts</option>
                            <option class="text-center" value="1">Cours Name 5pts</option>
                        </select>
                        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-success"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
                        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></button>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <select class="form-control">
                            <option class="text-center" value="1">Bronze Excel</option>
                            <option class="text-center" value="">Silver Anglais</option>
                        </select>
                        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-success"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
                        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></button>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr> 
            <%  
            }; %>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: When logging the member, does it not return member with his courses?

Comment: No, it's an admin who want to see the course of his participant